# Jumbotron / Wells in Twitter Bootstrap

Tags: twitter-bootstrap, twitter-bootstrap-3

What's the difference between [Jumbotron](http://getbootstrap.com/components/#jumbotron) and [Wells](http://getbootstrap.com/components/#wells) in bootstrap?  In what use cases is each preferred over the other?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Jumbotrons are full width (with no margins and out of grid) while wells are boxes with full-width which fit within grid.

Check these:

**Jumbotron Example --**
http://inspirationedge.com/
Home slider (having full width background images is a jumbotron.

**Well Example:** 
http://getbootstrap.com/examples/navbar-fixed-top/

I guess this explain use case as well .

Comment: Note that jumbotron will only be full width if it is not inside a container. The well is also full width outside of a container.

While the well may be intended to use inside containers, the only actual  difference is the styling of text and the default background colors.

Answer (score 3):

Jumbotron:
Intended to highlight Key Information. This Component comes with some styling for the H1 and p. Whereas with a well, you could technically achieve the same results, you would have to create your own styles.

Wells:
Just a simple inset highlight effect to highlight other information.

Bottom line: Not a HUGE difference, but as far as use case importance, Jumbotron is higher than a Well.

NOT to be confused with the Carousel which can look like a Jumbotron, but the Carousel includes the functionality of the rotating images.